# Является ли сравнением

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: *"Как от удара молотом по наковальне(,) брызнул в тишину звук"*? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как от удара молотом по наковАльне**, брызнул в тишину звУк.

Оборот **обособляется**, но это не сравнение, а **уподобление** (частный случай сравнения), например: **Словно белою косынкой** повязалася сосна. Такие обороты обособляются реже, чем сравнительные. Их отличительная особенность состоит в том, что союз КАК можно убрать, и грамматика  (не семантика) предложения от этого не изменится.

**Примечание.** В сравнительных оборотах  сравниваются два предмета, два признака, два действия: **Как удар (И.п.) молота, брызнул в тишину звук (И.п.)**, это классическое сравнение (звук как удар).

Обособление оборотов со значением уподобления зависит **от распространенности, позиции, структуры предложения**. В данном случае оборот распространенный, **выделяется паузой и запятой** (интонация  предложения, состоящего из дух фраз).

Пример необособленного нераспространенного оборота: **Как от удара** рассыпалась ночная тишина ― забурлили, забормотали тетерева-косачи, так забурлили, будто в их чёрных горлах собрались все весенние ручьи. [Юрий Коваль. Лесник Булыга (1985)]

Comment: _Sibylla: В данном случае оборот распространенный, выделяется **паузой** и **тире**_. ===  При чтении с логическим ударением на обороте "как от удара молотом **по наковальне**" (а не на сказуемом "брызнул") паузы может и не быть. И по поводу **тире**: а где оно в разбираемом предложении?

Comment: Slava, речь идет, конечно,  о запятой, ответ исправлен, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

«Брызнувший» звук напомнил и сопоставляется по силе со звуком удара молота. Очевидное сравнение и — запятая.

Answer (score 1):

***Как от удара молотом по наковальне, брызнул в тишину звук.*** Да, фраза ***как от удара молотком по наковальне*** является сравнительным оборотом, поэтому **запятая в конце этого оборота нужна**.